# pre select a select option dynamically when edit the form in php codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i'm getting dropdown options dynamically in selecting options when editing a record it is not showing the particular select option.
here is code

```
<select name="clientid" id="clientid" style="width:205px;" value="<?php echo $testimonial_id; ?>"> 
    <?php 

       foreach($test as $row)
       { 

           echo '<option value="'.$row->client_id.'">'.$row->client_name.'</option>';

       }
    ?>
</select>
```

here i want to pre select the particular option when i edit .

Comment: Could show of your full form

Comment: its better to use `form_select('clientid', array('options'), selection);`